# Trying to read from scanner using a constant string delimiter - java.util.scanner

Tags: java, file, delimiter, meta

I've been trying to find a way to read some data from a file delimited by a constant string delimiter.

The delimiter includes meta-characters, and I'm trying to split ONLY where it appears, so regex is not suitable.

Can someone advise a way for me, I know how to implement my own method to do this, what I'm asking is whether or not there's something built-in to java to do this.

Example:

John %#@!~23s,243 doe %#@!~23s,243 went %#@!~23s,243 to market to buy some milk.

Would result in.

Call 1: `.next()` --> John
Call 2: `.next()` --> doe
Call 3: `.next()` --> went
Call 4: `.next()` --> to market to buy some milk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The delimiter includes meta-characters, and I'm trying to split ONLY where it appears, so regex is not suitable.

You can still use a regex for the delimiter - just use [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to make sure "special" characters in regular expressions don't interfere.

That's assuming you still want to use `Scanner`, of course. You could use the [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class within [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)

Comment: Would using pattern.quote only result in %#@!~23s,243 being split? or would other assortments of the same characters also be split? That's why I thought regex couldn't be used because my understanding was that it doesn't check the order in which the characters appear.

Comment: @JackSmith: No, it's a pattern - not just a set of characters. A pattern *can* be a set of characters, but it isn't in general.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure where you're running into issues.  This should work:

Code:

```
    String input = "John %#@!~23s,243 doe %#@!~23s,243 went %#@!~23s,243 to market to buy some milk.";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s+" + Pattern.quote("%#@!~23s,243") + "\\s+");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Token: ." + scanner.next() + ".");
    }
```

Output:

```
Token: .John.
Token: .doe.
Token: .went.
Token: .to market to buy some milk..
```

The `Pattern.quote()` isn't strictly necessary for that example String (doesn't contain meta-characters), but may be needed depending on the actual input.